# How to attach call flow which I have created to routing profile?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-connect

I have created call flow using lambda integration and publish. I am not getting from where I should attached newly created call flow to routing profile.

Regards,
Mitesh

Answer (score 1):

Routing profiles are associated with queues, not a particular contact flow. Find out which queue(s) your contact flow is placing callers into and then add those queues to a routing profile. From there, assign the routing profile to agent(s) to handle those calls.